# dataTables: Sort date not working well using Bootstrap in RTL website

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sorting, datatables

[This is](https://jsfiddle.net/davseveloff/v7oozsLv/2/) a fiddle of my table:
The table order by date breaks in the seconf page.

As you can see the sorting is not working very good (second page).
At my website it is even worst. the sorting sorts firs the day (dd) than the month(mm) and finally the year(yyyy) for example 02/10/2015 will appear before 10/2/2017.

As well I have a double arrow at the sort  that does not appear in the fiddle, What can cause it?

[image]

This is the script I am using:

```
            $('#leadtable').dataTable({
              language: {
                url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/i18n/Hebrew.json'
              },

              columnDefs: [{
                  type: 'de_datetime',
                  targets: 0
                }

              ]
            });
```

Any help would be great, the problem can be seen better in my website. I would give the password and username if anyone would ask for to see the problem live.

Comment: When sorting dates you cannot sort on the string itself - you can use data attributes and sort on epoch time derived from the date

Comment: thank you, what does it means? the 'columnDefs' is not required here? could you please point me to a source that could help me?

Comment: This should help - they use a slightly different approach but will give you the general idea https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2467/need-help-for-sorting-date-with-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, You could easily sort on the date strings without any code (built into dataTables even with autodetection if and only if **all** values in the column is valid date strings)

Comment: What is a valid string?  is dd/mm/yyyy a valid date string?

Comment: @davidkonrad That's interesting - it failed for me when I tried hence going down the epoch route which works well - will read more, thanks

Comment: @DavSev,  `mm/dd/yyyy` is a valid string, `dd/mm/yyyy` is not. It simply need to be [RFC2822](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3) compliant. If not you need either to convert the date strings or use for example moment.js, which there is a plugin to in dataTables. But below is the easiest in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues :

1. You have mixed content in the date column. In fact the date part is the minor part of the columns HTML. You would need to extract the date value, for example by a preparing

   ```
   $.fn.dataTableExt.ofnSearch['extract-date'] = function(value) { ... }
   ```

   and by that be able to use native date sorting by `type: 'date'`
2. But this will not work, since your dates is in european style dd/mm/yyyy, you must convert the dates as well. The best you can do is to build your own date-parser plugin. Here is how you could solve your specific scenario :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "extract-date-pre": function(value) {
        var date = $(value, 'span')[0].innerHTML;
        date = date.split('/');
        return Date.parse(date[1]+'/'+date[0]+'/'+date[2])
    },
    "extract-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0))
    },
    "extract-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0))
    }
});
```

usage :

```js
columnDefs: [{
   type: 'extract-date',
   targets: [0]
}
```

**Note**: I have not made any sanity checks in `extract-date-pre`. It would be wise to test the `date` array before blindly trying to `parse()` the items.

Updated working fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/v7oozsLv/3/**

---

For the multiple arrow problem it is caused by your mix of versions between plugins and CSS, i.e bootstrap and your setup. I cant help since I dont know your setup. Have answered this issue several times, and it would be a pure guess without code. Somewhere, I believe, you have `dataTables.bootstrap.css` and `dataTables.bootstrap.js` but not using it right. Read the docs and try by error.